# How to i Get Client System MAC Address from Bigrock Cpanel using PHP

Tags: php, cpanel

I have used below mentioned php code for get mac address from client system it working fine in my local system(Windows OS). When i used this code on my Bigrock Cpanel it shows empty page. please clarify this issue.

```
 Example:
ob_start();
system('ipconfig /all'); 
$mycom=ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

$findme = 'Physical';
$pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme);
$mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+36),17);

echo $mac;
```

Comment: does `Bigrock Cpanel` run on Linux?

Comment: yes it runs based on Linux

Comment: `ipconfig` is a windows command - `ifconfig` is the Linux equivalent https://linuxconfig.org/linux-ipconfig-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Try with this php code:

```
<?php

  ob_start();
  system('/sbin/ifconfig -a');
  $mycom=ob_get_contents();
  ob_clean();
  $findme = 'physique';
  $pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme);

  $mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+38),22);
  echo "$mac\r";

  ?>
```

This works just fine on my CentOS 6.9 linux server:

```
64/5236# php get-mac.php
00:1A:10:1F:0A:1E
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan Stoica i try this code but same error will come(it shows empty)

Comment: what OS do you have? CentOS 6.x? 7.x?

Comment: Please check if you have php function system() enabled, it might be on the disabled functions list